# Flicker issue for 100% height, fixed position element

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, mobile-browser

I am implementing a side nav bar on my website.
For this I am following this tutorial link.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp
I am using Sidenav Overlay Example.
For referring the code use
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav 
HTML

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

CSS

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px; }

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s }

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1; }

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px; }
```

JavaScript

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

There are 2 issues that I am facing:
1) Flicker issue happens in mobile when I scroll the nav bar.
The issue happens when I scroll down and do not leave the touch screen, such that the URL bar of the browser disappears.
As soon as I leave the touch screen it renders properly.
It happens only in mobile devices.
[image: Normal]
Portrait Issue
[image: Portrait Issue]
Landscape Issue
[image: Landscape Issue]

The height of the side nav bar is 100%, when I make it of a very large fixed height then it works on Android devices but not in iOS devices.
Also with fixed height the side nav bar no longer stays scrollable if the number of elements in the side nav bar are more than the viewport size.
2) The background is scrollable even when I am moving my finger on top of the side nav bar.
I tried to make overflow hidden for the body when the nav bar is open, but it is not working in UCBrowser, iOS devices.

Comment: We need to see your code. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @MichaelCoker I have done the same. Please, check it out